# Aumentar numero con caracter incluido

Tags: javascript

he hecho un programa que lo que hace es que al presionar en la pantalla se suma un número constantemente cada vez que presionas, lo que quiero hacer es que al llegar al número 1000 se ponga un asterisco y continue contando empezando desde el 1, así quedaría de la siguiente forma:
1,2,3,4....998,999,*,*1,*2.....*998,*999,**,**1,**2... etc... he intentado separar un substring para saber si el primer carácter es * o no, pero el programa ha dejado de funcionar

```js
function inicio() {
    let num = 0;
    let numero = document.getElementById("numero");
    let boton = document.getElementById("boton");

    boton.onclick = function (e) {
        char1 = num.substring(0,1);
        alert(char1);
        if (num == 1000 || char1 == "*") {
            numero.textContent = "*" + parseInt(num) + 1;
            num++;
        }
        else {
            numero.textContent = parseInt(num) + 1;
            num++;
        }
    }
}
inicio()
```

```css
#boton {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 97.5vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    font-size: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pantalla">
    <button id="boton"><span id="numero">0</span></button>
</div>
```

Si alguien sabe la causa de este problema y puede comentarla lo agradecería mucho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás mezclando números con texto: num es un número y no puedes usar substring sobre ese tipo.

Se me ocurre que podrías solucionarlo de un modo más sencillo (he rebajado la comprobación de 1000 a 10 para llegar rápido, pero por lo demás todo debería funcionar):

```js
function inicio() {
    let num = 0;
    let numero = document.getElementById("numero");
    let boton = document.getElementById("boton");
    let char = "";
    boton.onclick = function (e) {
        num++; //aumentamos el contador de clicks
        if (num == 10) {
            char += "*"; //añadimos un *
            num = 0; //reiniciamos el contador
            numero.textContent = char; //en este caso sólo mostramos asteriscos
        } else {
          numero.textContent = char + num; //concatenamos
        }
    }
}
inicio()
```

```css
#boton {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 97.5vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    font-size: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pantalla">
    <button id="boton"><span id="numero">0</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias.